# Function call on left hand side of the assignment must return Variant or Object, finding common values in two arrays

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel, for-loop

I've got two arrays and I'm trying to pull out the common values in them and the function findUniques is supposed to return the strings (they're names) concatenated and separated by a comma. I think I'm close but I can't find what's wrong. I get an error in line 10

```
Function findUniques(astrArray1() As String, astrArray2() As String) As String

    Dim blnMP5 As Boolean
    blnMP5 = False
    Dim counter1 As Long
    Dim counter2 As Long

    For counter1 = LBound(astrArray1) To UBound(astrArray1)
        For counter2 = LBound(astrArray1) To UBound(astrArray2)
            If astrArray1(counter1) = astrArray2(counter2) Then
                blnMP5 = False
                If blnMP5 = True Then
                    findUniques() = findUniques & "," & "astrArray1()"
                End If
            End If
        Next counter2
    Next counter1

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable to hold the string you are building

```
    Dim tempString as string
```

And add this at line 10

```
    tempString = tempString & "," &  astrArray1(counter1)
```

And finally

```
    findUniques = tempString 
End function
```

Comment: The cause of the problem was likely identified in the answer by Kenneth. While the present answer solved the issue of the OP, it was likely due to removing the line that caused the error. This note aims at stating that it is not mandatory to use an auxiliary string variable to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is in this line:

```
findUniques() = findUniques & "," & "astrArray1()"
```

You're trying to assign a value to a function call, which doesn't make sense.

You should declare a variable in the start of your function and keep on adding to that one and eventually return it:

```
Function findUniques(astrArray1() As String, astrArray2() As String) As String

    Dim blnMP5 As Boolean
    blnMP5 = False    
    Dim counter1 As Long
    Dim counter2 As Long  
    Dim uniquesString as String = ""

    For counter1 = LBound(astrArray1) To UBound(astrArray1)
        For counter2 = LBound(astrArray1) To UBound(astrArray2)
            If astrArray1(counter1) = astrArray2(counter2) Then
               blnMP5 = False
               If blnMP5 = True Then
                   uniquesString = uniquesString & "," & "astrArray1()"
               End If
             End If
        Next counter2
     Next counter1

End Function
```