# Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object while evaluating if statement with function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting this error in the following piece of code:

```
Dim posOfProdInArray As Integer
If isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray(firstCellOfRowTBRead.Offset(0, 2).Value, aggregatedProdsAndTheirData, posOfProdInArray) Then
    sumOfActualDay = sumOfActualDay + firstCellOfRowTBRead.Offset(0, 4).Value * aggregatedProdsAndTheirData(posOfProdInArray, 2)
End If
```

It occurs when isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray function is called.

Here's the function:

```
Public Function isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray( _
      stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant, _
      Optional ByRef varToReceivePositionOfString As Integer) As Boolean
Dim i
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = stringToBeFound Then
        isStringInArray = True
        If IsMissing(varToReceivePositionOfString) Then
        Else
            varToReceivePositionOfString = i
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
isStringInArray = False
End Function
```

Comment: Btw your function always returns `False`, unless your function is actually called `isStringInArray`.

Comment: The function does not even compile. You are missing an `End if`. And `isStringInArray ` is not declared.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function  for `IsMissing` - "Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an optional **Variant*** argument has been passed to a procedure."  Your parameter `varToReceivePositionOfString` is declared as `Integer`

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: The function has a missing `EndIf`. Also you are not returning anything: Your function is named `isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray` but you are assigning the value to `isStringInArray`. Have you copied the function code from another function called `isStringInArray`? That would explain the error message you mention in the question title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment: There are several issues with the code you show.

The code doesn't compile at all because you are missing an `End If`.

The next issue is that you are not returning anything. In VBA, you need to assign the return value to the function itself (as if the function was a variable). Your function name is `isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray`, and therefore you need to write `isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray = True`.

It looks as if you have copied the function from another function called `isStringInArray` and not adjusted the name when assigning the return value. Assuming that a function `isStringInArray` still exists in your code, that would explain the error message you show in the title: `isStringInArray = False` looks to VBA as if you are assigning something to that function and that is not allowed (and would makes no sense).

Minor thing: As Tim Williams already mentioned, the `isMissing` will not work on optional parameters others than `Variant`. However, that doesn't matter, you can completly remove that check.

Your function could look like

```
Public Function isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant, Optional ByRef varToReceivePositionOfString As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = stringToBeFound Then
            isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray = True
            varToReceivePositionOfString = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    isStringInFirstColumnOfMultidimensionalArray = False
End Function
```

Assigning `False` as return value can be removed also (because it's the default value for a Boolean), I kept it only for better readability.

Comment: I'd still VTC as a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157111/function-call-on-left-hand-side-of-the-assignment-must-return-variant-or-object), but definitely a valid answer.

Comment: @BigBen: You are probably right. I saw your about the dupe comment too late, however, the linked question had a slightly different problem: There was an extra `()` at the left side of the return value assignment, while here it is the (accidentally) attempt to assign something to a *different* function. Almost sure that was also already asked, but I will not waste any time so look for it.

Comment: [Another dupe link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351900/error-function-call-on-left-side-of-assignment-must-return-variant-or-object). Maybe not worth VTC'ing I guess, but this issue has definitely occurred before.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the same problem, however, it was not pointed out why the error message was thrown. If you simply use a wrong name, either you get a "Variable not defined" (when you use `Option Explicit`) or nothing happens at all. The error with the *left-hand side* occurs only if you use a name that is an existing function - which is usually the case if you *copy* a function and forget to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `IsMissing` to determine if an argument was passed to a parameter marked as `Optional` then that parameter needs to be declared as a `Variant`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an optional Variant
> argument has been passed to a procedure.

Comment: You are right, however, VBA will not complain, and the code will run, even if the optional parameter is omitted.

Comment: Yep - I should have tested...